# What does "in parts" mean?

Tags: meaning

Can you clarify the meaning of bold parts in

> The Drama Society is now auditioning **for parts** in the **student play**.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parts is referring to acting parts. So another word for it would be **roles** in a play. Student play is like an acting performance put on by students (so people in school)